# Django Model Save Method: Pass raw data to calculate final data for write to db

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm reading in a Excel report via xlrd and then creating a Tablib dataset for bulk importing via django-report-tools. My current Model has a bunch of custom methods that take the values that were saved to the db and then performs additional logic.

Currently the Models have been set up to mirror the structure of the excel report / source system for ease of import. I now realize that this requires me to create a bunch of custom Model methods so that I can return data that I really care about into my app. For example, the source data has a due date and a revised due date. I'm only interested in having the 'Actual Due Date' so I have a method that spits back the appropriate date. (This is just an example, there are quite a few different cases that require similar hygiene).

This obviously has resulted in a lot of needless data in my database so I'm going to rework the Models to be more precise.

Is it possible to pass in all the report values for a single record into the Model.save() method and then perform my clean up there? I would be handing in some variables that wouldn't get saved to the database. If so, can you point me in the right direction because my Google searches have come up empty. [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) makes me think this isn't possible with the bulk jobs I'm running. But would this even be possible if I wasn't bulk importing?

Or is it better practice for me just to rework the import jobs to do those calculations before and then just hand the ORM a pristine dataset? Thanks for any help you can provide.

** I'm running Django 1.6 on Python 2.7.

Comment: What do you mean with "pass in all the report values for a single record"? Do all the excel rows get stored in one table row (i.e. one model instance)?

Comment: The excel report has multiple columns. The model schema mirrors the report structure right now but I'd like do some analysis on those columns for each row and only save data to the database that I need. Just not sure if it's possible for the model save method to take all the fields for each excel row and then only save the fields that pass the logic I set up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it in the save method but using a ModelForm seems a better fit for this. Something like this:

```
# models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    extracted_data_1 = models.IntegerField()
    # more fields
    ...


# forms.py

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cell_a = forms.IntegerField()
    cell_b = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cell_a = self.cleaned_data['cell_a']
        cell_b = self.cleaned_data.get('cell_b', 0)
        self.cleaned_data['extracted_data_1'] = cell_a + cell_b
        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('cell_a', 'cell_b', 'extracted_data_1')
```

Each excel row would have to be processed by the form and if it's valid, just do `form.save()`.